# What is the difference between [\s\S]*? and .*?

Tags: ruby, regex

I've encountered the following token in a regular expression: `[\s\S]*?`

If I understand this correctly, the character class means "match a whitespace character or a non-whitespace character". Therefore, would this not do exactly the same thing as `.*?`

One possible difference is that usually `.` does not match newlines. However, this regular expression was written in Ruby and was passed the [`m` modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html) meaning that the `.` does, in fact, match newlines.

Is there any other reason to use `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?`

In case it helps, the regular expression I am looking at appears inside the [sprockets library](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/blob/master/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb) in the HEADER_PATTERN constant on line 97. The full expression is:

```
/
  \A \s* (
    (\/\* ([\s\S]*?) \*\/) |
    (\#\#\# ([\s\S]*?) \#\#\#) |
    (\/\/ ([^\n]*) \n?)+ |
    (\# ([^\n]*) \n?)+
  )
/mx
```

Comment: I share your speculation. Maybe, it might help if you give us the whole regxp or the context in which it is used.

Comment: Thanks for adding the regex. Now, it looks even more strange because it's using `m`, and is tying to deal with it using `[^\n]`.

Comment: An important lesson to take away from this is that not all the information on the internet is valid. There is no vetting process like there'd be in print on paper, so there is a lot of bad information out there, and, unfortunately, it's up to us to sift the wheat from the chaff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You interpreted the regex correctly.

That seems like a relict from other languages which do not support the m-flag (or s-flag in other implementations).

A reason to use that construct would be to not use the m-flag so you have the possibility to use . without matching newlines but are still able to match everything if need be.

Comment: That's a great thought and a possible use case

Comment: This might be the right answer. However, ruby has a notation for this purpose: `(?m:.)`. This will put `.` in `m` mode without making the whole regex in `m` mode. Whomever used the original regex is not doing a good coding.

Comment: @sawa I agree to both statements

Answer (score 1):

With the m flag, they would be the same except that `.*` would be a lot clearer and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The newline thing is the only difference.  Maybe somebody thought it was easier to read without having to know the m context, or wanted it to be robust against a change to that context.

I have seen `[^]*` used for a similar purpose.