# Determining distance between characters

Tags: javascript, regex

If the characters 'a' and 'b' are separated by exactly 3 places anywhere in a string return true.

Can you point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Determine the position of `a` and `b` (`indexOf()`). Subtract. Take absolute value.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz That only works if the first `a` or the first `b` is part of the match. It will fail if there are `a` or `b` instances that precede the match, as in `afoeahooawieb`.

Answer (score 1):

For "*a string includes two characters, '`a`' and '`b`', which have 3 chars in between*", this would do it:

```
/a[\S\s]{3}b/.test(str)
```

where `[\S\s]` really matches everything, you could also use `.` instead. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6168826/1048572) for the difference.

If you want to match appearances in both directions, you will use `/(a.{3}b|b.{3}a)/` instead.

Comment: Any reason to use `[\S\s]` instead of `.`?

Comment: @zerkms, `\n` is not included in `.`.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen: I highly doubt OP included `\n` as a "place"

Comment: @zerkms, I would assume place is any character, but I agree he should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something along the lines of:

```
return (Math.abs(str.indexOf('a') - str.indexOf('b')) == 3)
```

Here's an implementation demonstration:

```
function distanceBetween(el, a, b, d) {
    if (!el || !a || !b || !d) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        var str = el.firstChild.nodeValue;
        return (Math.abs(str.indexOf(a) - str.indexOf(b)) == d)
    }
}

var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
    a = 'a',
    b = 'b',
    d = 3;

for (var i = 0, len = lis.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (distanceBetween(lis[i], a, b, d)) {
        lis[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f90';
    }
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/92Hxp/).

As noted, in the comments below, this solution fails if there are multiple examples of the first matched letter. See the demo provided by Jonathan Sampson: http://jsfiddle.net/92Hxp/1/ (the third string, `acdae0rbe`, should still match).

Comment: Still appears to fail when `a` or `b` appears in the string prior to the beginning of a match. http://jsfiddle.net/92Hxp/1/ I've changed the value of the third `li`, but it still contains a substring that *should* match: `ae0rb`.

Comment: Ah; I see what you mean now. Yeah; without going into exceedingly complex solutions I can't see there being a solution as simple as the regex possibility. Darn.

Comment: I'm suspecting that myself, though I'm personally not super pleased with the regex solution, to be completely honest.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var string = 'a123b';  // String you're testing.
/a.{3}b/.test(string);
```

Add any RegEx modifiers you might need (i.e. `i`).

Answer (score 0):

I would use JavaScript's native `match()` method, which will not only tell you if your pattern is found, but will return the matched substrings as well.

```
var str = "afoeahooawieb00183b123Axo",
    fnd = false;

if ( fnd = str.match(/a.{3}b|b.{3}a/gi) ) {
  console.log( fnd );
}
```

Which outputs:

```
["awieb", "b123A"]
```